# Where is the root route in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It used to be that routes.rb had a root route line. But I don't see it anymore even though when I run the server I see the "Yay! You’re on Rails!" page. I can't find where it is defined so I can override it!

Comment: This behavior is actually Rails rescuing a routing error which occurs if you don't have a route defined for `/` much in the same way that the framework catches `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` by rendering `/public/404.html` and other errors by rendering `500.html`. If my memory serves correctly it has been handled this way since at least Rails 4. I'm not sure a which point the html file rendered was moved into the framework (previous versions generated a `/public/index.hmtl` file). But if you actually add a `/public/index.hmtl` it will be rendered instead.

Comment: And of couse adding a `root to: 'controller#action'` route prevents the routing error from being raised in the first place.

Comment: The reason why its implemented like this is that a generated app should raise an exception and error out in production instead of exposing to the world that its a rails app which would happen if rails generated a default route. Remember programmers are lazy.

Answer (score 5):

On a new project it doesn't use a `root` route, it just renders the rails' default new project page.

Just add the line:

```
root to: 'somecontroller#someaction'
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

The `routes.rb` file is in the `config/` directory of your rails project. You can define a root route there and direct it using the [routes DSL](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 2):

Above answers are correct but incomplete.

With Rails 6 it seems that there's no explicit root route ('/'). Instead the rails gem(s) handle it by displaying the standard "Yay you're on Rails" page (see railsties/templates/welcome/index.html.erb). It's a fixed page, bypassing routes.rb and layouts etc.

This behavior seems to only happen in development mode and when you haven't actually defined a root route.

So it seems that the page is fixed and unmodifiable. But it can easily be replaced by a root route.

Comment: For completeness, you need to add `root 'controller#action'` to add a default root route